# Can a chrome extension monitor secure cookies for a permitted domain in the manifest file?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension

I want to monitor authentication cookies from my website in my chrome extension but they are secure. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. [`chrome.cookies` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) provides access to all cookies, including ones with Secure and HTTPOnly flags, for sites you have host permissions for.

Comment: this is a huge security problem...

Comment: @Dinesh How so? Extensions have to request host permissions for domains they need access to. Extensions in general are "more powerful" than website code, on purpose.

Comment: my reasoning was.. If a 3rd party extension has access to my gmail cookies from my browser session. Then technically they could log in using that cookie, no? (Of course, Gmail has more than just a session cookie for authorization. ) But most websites just rely on just a session cookies.